# Extract Href using scrapy python

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract href from below css

```
<a aria-label="Flap Diaper Bag. By Burberry Kids. $1,190.00. Style: Archive Beige. " data-style-id="4851207" itemprop="url" class="Qc" href="/p/burberry-kids-flap-diaper-bag-archive-beige/product/9121644/color/822967"><meta itemprop="image" content="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61DsRY3+IDL._AC_SX255_.jpg">
  <div class="nc Cc">
    <p class="_c">Luxury</p>
    <span class="sg wg">
      <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61DsRY3+IDL._AC_SX255_.jpg"class="" alt="Archive Beige"> 
    </span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to aid you. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a quicker response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `response.css('[itemprop="url"] ::attr(href)').extract_first()`